# Save User Preference for Default View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wanting to have my app show a view on first launch that lets the user select the default view controller to open every time they launch the app. For example, the first time a user launches the app they are presented with a screen that has options to select News, Weather, My Account, etc. If they select News, the new view controller is opened and every time the app is launched, the News view is shown by default. There would then be a preferences section of the main menu that allows the user to change their default view. I'm just not sure how to go about implementing this and storing the user preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can make user of [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html)

If you are creating your views from Storyboard then you can directly save the storyboard id or else you can just store the name of the view.

**To save user's preference**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"News" forKey:@"myPreferredView"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**To present the view if there's an user preference**

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myPreferredView"]) {
    NSString *preferedView  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myPreferredView"];

    // present user's preferred view here
}

else {
    // present your default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save there choice using `NSUserDafaults`.  This allows you to store data locally on a users device and access it as needed.  In your case you could have your application open and read from `NSUserDefaults` to determine what view should load.  Refer to Apples Class Reference on `NSUserDefaults` for more information how to implement it https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html